# How to get current browser in RFT test script

Tags: java, javascript, rft

I have my webpage opened using RFT. In that page, I have a link I want to click.
For that I am using

```
objMap.ClickTabLink(objMap.document_eBenefitsHome(), "Upload Documentation", "Upload Documentation");
```

The current page link name is "Upload Documentation"

I know that `objMap.document_eBenefitsHome()` takes it back to the initial page, what can I use in that place which uses the "current page opened" ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives that could solve your problem:

- Open the `Test Object Map`; select from the map the object that represents the document `document_eBenefitsHome`; modify the `.url` property using regular expression, so that the URLs of the two pages you cited in your question match the regex.
- Find dinamically the document object using the `find` method. Once the page containing the link you want to click was fully loaded, try to use this code to find the document: `find(atDescendant(".class", "Html.HtmlDocument"), false)`. The `false` boolean value allow the `find` method to search also among object that are not previously recorded.